# Cannot access public methods through dll

Tags: c#

I've a function `QMain()` whose return type is `object`.

```
public class QMain
{
    public object objQ(string str)
    {
        if (str.ToUpper() == "A")
        {
            clsA objA = new clsA();
            return objA;
        }
        else if (str.ToUpper() == "B")
        {
            clsB objB = new clsB();
            return objB;
        }
        else
            return "";
    }

}
```

Following is `clsA`:

```
public class clsA 
{
   public string strMessage { get; private set; }
   public static string staticField;
   public bool cantAccessThisFn(string str)
   {...}
}
```

Both of the above classes are in same project which is a class library. I've created another console application wherein I've included the above project's `dll`. Now, I'm doing:

```
QMain obj=new QMain();
object A=obj.objQ("A");
```

I can get `strMessage`, `staticField` but not `cantAccessThisFn`. If I directly make an object of `clsA`, I'm able to get `cantAccessThisFn`. Is there any way to get access to this function from obj (object of class `QMain`)?
I get the following error:

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'cantAccessThisFn' and no extension method 'cantAccessThisFn' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

Comment: I'm not how you're "getting" any of those fields. Type `object` has no such fields, and that is what you're working with, unless you cast to one of your types.

Comment: you want to access `cantAccessThisFn` from `clsA.cantAccessThisFn`? or from an instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to help you understand! and **not the recommended solution.**

Marked Patricks answer up, as that is the more correct way...
 **but to achieve what you had** you could do something like.

Also I applied the standard naming camel cases for the Classes, Properties and local variables.

This also allows for ClsA and ClsB to have completely different Method/Property names. **Again I am not suggesting this as the way to do it but to rather help understand what its happening.**

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

        QMain obj = new QMain();
        object a = obj.objQ("A");

        //FYI the below commended out is not possible...
        //ClsA.staticField is but that is not the instance you created.
        //------------
        //a.staticField //<--- not possible
        //------------

        var someA = a as ClsA; //<--- attempts to cast it as ClsA
        var someB = a as ClsB; //<--- attempts to cast it as ClsB
        if (someA != null) //check if the cast was successful
        {
            var var1 = someA.StrMessage;
        }
        else if (someB != null)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}

public class QMain
{
    public object objQ(string str)
    {
        if (str.ToUpper() == "A")
        {
            ClsA objA = new ClsA();
            return objA;
        }
        else if (str.ToUpper() == "B")
        {
            ClsB objB = new ClsB();
            return objB;
        }
        else
            return "";
    }

}

public class ClsA
{
    public string StrMessage { get; private set; }
    public static string StaticField;
    public bool CantAccessThisFn(string str)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public class ClsB
{
    public string StrMessageMyC { get; private set; }
    public static string StaticFieldMyC;
    public bool CantAccessThisFnMyC(string str)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Seabizkit, I don't want to use ClsA/ ClsB.

Comment: Hi ? its was marked as the answer.... and now not? confused... could you let me know what you mean? thanks

Answer (score 5):

The problem is your `objQ` method returns an `object`. You haven't defined any (extension) methods on `object`, so `cantAccessThisFn` definitely can't be accessed.

What you should do is this: create an interface with all methods you want to share between the two classes, and don't return `object`, but return `IYourInterfaceName`. Then you can access those methods and properties defined on the interface.

Something like this:

```
public class clsA : IYourInterface
{
    ...
}

public interface IYourInterface
{
    string strMessage { get; }
    bool cantAccessThisFn(string str);
}
```

Then your method should look like:

```
public IYourInterface objQ(string str)
{ ... }
```

And your assignment like this:

```
IYourInterface a = obj.objQ("A");
```

*Now* it is valid to call:

```
a.cantAccessThisFn("z");
```

Comment: Hi Patrick, the problem is ClsA and ClsB have different set of functions. Is there any other way out?

Comment: Yes, but it feels like a design flaw to me. You can check the type of the field, as Seabizkit answered, but I wouldn't recommend that. Why did you design your code as it is now?

Comment: there are various classes,each designated with a string and we wanted to access functions of those classes via that string in other project. Do you have any other efficient way for this?

Comment: @pika, technically i think you should open a new question then. My answer does explain how to do it with your current code, my answer does not address your design problems but does address the issue with the code as it stands. I believe you need to ask a new question.... along the lines of how do i design xyz to achieve xyz given x or y.